# Unity Render.TransparentGeometry performance issue

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 2d, render, frame-rate

I'm developing a 2D pixel game in Unity (5.5.0f3). Now I'm almost finished the game. It gives 60 fps in editor, and around 10 fps on my android tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab 3). Here's what profiler shows
[Profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr0Kf.jpg)

I'm not using transparent sprites. All gameobjects have deffault pixel snap shader.

How can I fix it?

Comment: We need to see specific code. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

TAB 3 GPU issues might be related to size of your transparent sprites? Are they compressed, sized to an appropriate resolution such as 128x128 instead of default 2048x2048 etc?